# Vectorized pandas operations with enum.Flag throws TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I was experimenting with some flag objects in Python 3.6 and pandas '0.20.1' and found that pandas does not properly route the operations I initiate when holding enum flag objects

```
import pandas
import enum

# Ok example with bools...
dfBool = pandas.DataFrame( { 'a':[True,True,False,False], 'b':[True,False,True,False]} )
dfBool['a'] | dfBool['b']
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

# Broken example with enum.Flag...
flag = enum.Flag('flg' , ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] )
dfFlag = pandas.DataFrame( { 'c1':[flag.a, flag.b, flag.c, flag.d] , 'c2':[flag.d, flag.c, flag.b, flag.a]} )
dfFlag
      c1     c2
0  flg.a  flg.d
1  flg.b  flg.c
2  flg.c  flg.b
3  flg.d  flg.a

dfFlag['c1'] | dfFlag['c2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 883, in na_op
    result = op(x, y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'flg' and 'bool'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 924, in wrapper
    return filler(self._constructor(na_op(self.values, other.values),
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 894, in na_op
    result = lib.vec_binop(x, y, op)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 894, in pandas._libs.lib.vec_binop (pandas\_libs\lib.c:15883)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 887, in pandas._libs.lib.vec_binop (pandas\_libs\lib.c:15755)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'flg' and 'bool'


# Workaround with lambda to push the operation elementwise...
dfFlg[['c1','c2']].apply( lambda r : r[0] | r[1] , axis=1)
0    flg.d|a
1    flg.c|b
2    flg.c|b
3    flg.d|a


# Numpy workaround with values array
dfFlag['c1'].values | dfFlag['c2'].values
array([<flg.d|a: 9>, <flg.c|b: 6>, <flg.c|b: 6>, <flg.d|a: 9>], dtype=object)
```

Is pandas still catching up with these new Python types, while numpy seems to already be up to date at least as of `numpy.__version__ = '1.12.1'` or at least coded more robustly somehow.